# Name of method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can I get the name of a method in TypeScript? For example like this:

```
class C {
    test() { return this.test.name; } // should return "test";
}
```

I can make it work for functions by extending the Function interface:

```
interface Function {
    name: string;
}

function f() {
    return f.name; // returns "f"
}
```

Can I make that work for methods as well, in some way?

Comment: If you add `interface Function {
    name: string;
}` it should work, no?

Comment: @PSL I have tried that, of course, and it does not seem to work. Check it out: http://bit.ly/1jXhYSk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is NO, there is no name for anonymous functions.

If your concern is compilation error then overriding the interface would be sufficient as interface is partial. But the way Typescript transpiles the `class` *there won't be any name for the instance methods as they are just references to anonymous functions*. i.e

It gets compiled to

```
var C = (function () {
    function C() {
    }

    C.prototype.test = function () {
                            // ^__ There is no name for the function so 
        return this.test.name; // this will just be empty
    };
    return C;
})();
```

You will see it printing `function.name` with value only if it had been like this:

```
 C.prototype.test = function test() {
                             // ^__ Not anonymous anymore
```

One way i can think of is to use a decorator and set value for a property say `propName`.

```
interface Function {
    propName?: string;
}

function setName(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    descriptor.value.propName =  propertyKey;
    //or target[propertyKey].propName = propertyKey;
    return descriptor;
}

class C {
    @setName
    test() {
        return this.test.propName;
    }
}
```

It all ties down to how Typescript transpiles the `class`. For instance if you were using Babel, [due to the way it transpiles](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%20return%20this.test.name%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20should%20return%20%22test%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A) the specs you will see that it assigns the value of the function reference as is to the property descriptor so it will retain the name.

Note: Not all browsers support [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) anyways (ex: older IE), also property `name` is not *Writable* across browsers as well, i.e you cannot change the name. So configure with another property.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this compilation to an anonymous function is my concern. Using traditional javascript I can just use method.name, so my question is how can I do that in Typescript. I am aware of how it is compiled, but what can I do to work around that?